# what is the correct method to match channel shape in cnn? transpose vs reshape

Tags: numpy, match, reshape, transpose, channel

I tried to build my CNN layer. but I had one problem.
The CNN layer's input is image data. and I used to the backend as TensorFlow. so the CNN layer's input shape must be (number of data, height, width, channel)!

I made the data to use the list. 
Let show example.
the image is 2x2 file. and the data is 'a', 'b', 'c'.

```
a = np.zeros((2,2))
b = np.ones((2,2))
c = np.ones((2,2)) * 2

l = [a,b,c]
l = np.array(l)
print(l)
print(l.shape)

print is

[[[0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[2. 2.]
  [2. 2.]]]
(3, 2, 2)
```

I want to input the 'l' data. but I was so confused.

To match the shape (number of data, height, width, channel),
what is the correct method transpose() or reshape().

the example's method output is here.

```
new = np.transpose(l, (1,2,0))
print("=============================")
print(new)
print(new.shape)
print("=============================")

old = np.reshape(l, (2,2,3))
print(old)
print(old.shape)

[[[0. 1. 2.]
  [0. 1. 2.]]

 [[0. 1. 2.]
  [0. 1. 2.]]]
(2, 2, 3)
=============================
[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 2.]
  [2. 2. 2.]]]
(2, 2, 3)
```

Two Method's shape is (2, 2, 3) so there's no error! but I had some suspicion.
I think the transpose method is right. but there's no evidence to use this method. what is correct?

Thank you.

Comment: As long as the total number of elements doesn't change, `reshape` works; but that doesn't mean that the arrangement of elements is what you need.  It's evident to me that the order of elements in the `new` case (transpose) is right, with each 'row' showing the desired `0,1,2` pattern.